# Chemmacros write next to reaction

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros

I am using the `chemmacros` package and I would like to know if it's possible to write next to a reaction, for example, like this:[image] Or maybe with the help of other package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={reactions,thermodynamics}}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\usepackage{helvet} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{reactions*}
    2 NH3\gas{} + 5/2 O2\gas{} &-> 3 H2O\gas{} + 2 NO\gas{}\\
    2 NH3\gas{} + 2 O2\gas{} &-> 3 H2O\gas{} + N2O\gas{}\\
    2 NH3\gas{} + 3/2 O2\gas{} &-> 3 H2O\gas{} + N2\gas{}
\end{reactions*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any special trick necessary to compile the code? I get `Paragraph ended before \@fileswith@ptions was complete.`

Comment: missing closing braces of \usepackage{babel} @valerie

Comment: @WeijunZhou Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding another alignment point:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={reactions,thermodynamics}}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\usepackage{helvet} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{reactions*}
    2 NH3\gas{} + 5/2 O2\gas{} &-> 3 H2O\gas{} + 2 NO\gas{}  & text\\
    2 NH3\gas{} + 2 O2\gas{} &-> 3 H2O\gas{} + N2O\gas{}  & text\\
    2 NH3\gas{} + 3/2 O2\gas{} &-> 3 H2O\gas{} + N2\gas{}  & text
\end{reactions*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works for me, but I seems that this way you can't use spaces, because it seems to ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

`chemmacros` has a special function to typeset such states:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={reactions,thermodynamics}}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\usepackage{helvet} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\NewChemState\foo{symbol=H,superscript=$\circ$,unit=\kilo\joule,subscript-pos=right}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \ch{2 NH3\gas{} + 5/2 O2\gas{} &-> 3 H2O\gas{} + 2 NO\gas{}} && \foo(A){+2035}  \\
    \ch{2 NH3\gas{} + 2 O2\gas{} &-> 3 H2O\gas{} + N2O\gas{}}&& \foo(B){+36}\\
    \ch{2 NH3\gas{} + 3/2 O2\gas{} &-> 3 H2O\gas{} + N2\gas{}}&& \foo(C){-285}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot.